# Overriding default tab behaviour in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing an application in Python using Tkinter to manage my GUI.

There is a text entry box on which I am trying to implement an autocompletion function which will bind to the Tab key.

I have bound the tab key to my entry box, but when I press tab, the program attempts to cycle between GUI elements.

How do I override this default behavior so that the GUI will only carry out my specified command on the key press?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Return `'break'` at the end of your event handler.  It interrupts event propagation.

```
def my_tab_handler(event):
    ... # handle tab event
    return 'break' # interrupts event propagation to default handlers
```